# How to match strings to large dictionary and avoid memory problems

Tags: r, regex, dictionary, memory

I have a dataframe with strings such as these, some of which are existing English words and others which are not:

```
df <- data.frame(
  strings = c("'tis"," &%#@","aah", "notexistingword", "823942", "abaxile"))
```

Now I'd like to check which of them are real words by matching them to a large dictionary such as the `GradyAugmented`;

```
library(qdapDictionaries)
df$inGrady <- grepl(paste0("\\b(", paste(GradyAugmented[1:2500], collapse = "|"), ")\\b"), df$strings)
df
          strings inGrady
1            'tis    TRUE
2            &%#@   FALSE
3             aah    TRUE
4 notexistingword   FALSE
5          823942   FALSE
6         abaxile    TRUE
```

Unfortunately, this works fine just as long as I restrict the size of `GradyAugmented` (the cut-off point from which it no longer seems to work is around size `2500`). As soon as I use the *whole* dictionary I get an error, asserting there's an `invalid regular expression`. My hunch is that it's less the regex but a memory problem. How can that problem be resolved?

Comment: Neither TRE nor PCRE support too long patterns. Not sure ICU would, you may check with `stringr::str_detect`

Comment: I think instead of having a long pattern argument > 2500..  It may be faster and should work if you do `pat <- paste0("\\b(", GradyAugmented[1:2500], ")\\b"); Reduce("|", lapply(pat, grepl, x = df$strings))`

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?

```
df$inGrady <- df$strings %in% GradyAugmented

#           strings inGrady
# 1            'tis    TRUE
# 2            &%#@   FALSE
# 3             aah    TRUE
# 4 notexistingword   FALSE
# 5          823942   FALSE
# 6         abaxile    TRUE
```

Comment: Well, it's a nice solution but what I was really after is an answer to my question why the `grepl` method runs into (apparently memory) problems and how to resolve them.

Comment: Actually, the use of word boundaries invalidates the suggested approach, since the strings should only be found if they are whole words.